# How to render different show templates conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got a `Post` model, and a post can be either a Video post (with YouTube link) or an Article post (with body text).
There is an enum `post_type` that determines the type of Post.

In my `show.html.erb` view I would like to display a different template file depending on the type of post displayed.

The entire `html.erb` file content is different for Articles and Videos.

In my controller I want to be able to check the post type and render a differnt file accordingly.

```
if @post.video?
    //render video show view `video_show.html.erb`
else
    // render article show view `article_show.html.erb`
end
```

I've already tried `render template: 'posts/video'` to render a new `posts/video.html.erb` file I created but that did not work at all.

What is the best way to do this? I want to follow convention and not use crude partials and a simple if-else to switch between partials.

Comment: Try inspecting the `enum` values. Does `@post.video?` return `true`?

Comment: I actually used another boolean in its place. IS render template the correct way to do it then?

Comment: Did you tried render file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple render works for you, you can use below code:

> ## Just render with HTML file name if file is in same controller's view

```
if @post.video?
  render 'video_show'
else
  render 'artical_show'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`render` works with just the relative file name

```
if @post.video?
  # with a file name posts/video_show.html.erb
  render 'posts/video_show'
else
  # with a file name posts/article_show.html.erb
  render 'posts/article_show'
end
```